# How to get email of a user Google Assistant actions

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google, actions-builder

I am working on a conversation using google actions conversation sdk. I want to personalize the experience, How do i get the email of the user ? I know i need to do account linking , the flow is already done using oAuth but question is how to trigger it when user is interacting with google assistant over voice. I want to check if user email is available else ask him/her to signin using my service account ( users signup over web).

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do account linking with the [Streamlined](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/gsi-oauth-concept-guide) account linking flow, which first requests the user's Google account and then your server can check whether that email address exists already. If so, the account linking proceeds. Otherwise you can create a flow that will let them create an account via voice.

The [implementation guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in-oauth) steps through how to setup the project information in the Actions Console and the server-side code to write to perform this verification:

[image]